# Adobe Illustrator 2018 Live Corner Edges not Showing to round rectangles and basic shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

> These live corner edges are missing in adobe illustrator. Rather than it is giving me a simple rectangle.

[image]

> My adobe illustrator version is 16.0.0. Kindly somebody, please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Illustrator Live Corners is a [17.0.0](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2175998&seqNum=4) version feature.

Instead you can always use **Round Corners** from menu **Effect** > **Stylize**

> Adobe Illustrator CS6: Rounding One (or Two) Corners
>
> - Select a rectangle.
> - Select the Scissors tool and click two opposing corners to separate the single rectangle > into two independent right angles
> - Select one of the right angles, and use **Effect** > **Stylize** > **Round Corners** to round one corner
> - Choose **Object** > **Expand Appearance**
> - Repeat steps 3 and 4 on the other right angle.

Answer (score 0):

My illustrator is CC 2015

and what you can do is go to
**view** > **show corner widget**

Answer (score 0):

Check that the object you are working on is not too small for using this feature. I was recently frustrated by the same issue only to realize when I scaled up the object, the live corner indicators magically appeared again!

Answer (score 0):

just press ctrl + H

```
                                                            x                                                                     v
```